# Messed up project directory; do we rebase?

Tags: git

My partner and I are working on a team project. 
Our project directory is supposed to look like this:

> ```
>    PERSON
>   __|____________________
>   |                     |
>   INSERT_PERSON     DELETE_PERSON
> ```

Where "Person" is a folder of related functions and "Insert_Person" and "Delete_Person" are folders of code. I rebased and pushed "Insert_Person" to stable, and then my partner rebased "Delete_Person" but has not pushed it yet.
We realized we forgot the parent folder, "Person".

> ```
>   |                     |
>   INSERT_PERSON     DELETE_PERSON
> ```

How do we put the Parent folder in at this point? Can he put it in before he pushes? Do I need to undo my rebase?

This problem is compounded because neither of us quite know how to visualize a rebase.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't create the parent folder after the fact (in a new commit, after your partner pushes)?

Comment: We're just not sure what is going to happen, so we're holding off on merging the delete folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: the simple solution, and the rewrite-history solution.

### The Simple Solution

The simplest solution is to just continue as you would have, and fix the issue after the fact. After your partner merges the "Delete Person" branch, you can do:

```
git checkout master # or whatever your stable branch is
git pull
mkdir PERSON
git mv INSERT_PERSON PERSON/
git mv DELETE_PERSON PERSON/
git commit -m "Fix folder structure"
git push
```

This will create a new commit that moves the two folders into the common folder. This shouldn't cause any issues, because Git is usually pretty good about tracking changes even across file renames.

### Rewriting History

You may prefer to not create that extra commit, and you might want your history to look like you never made the mistake in the first place. With Git, you can do this too.

First, do:

```
git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate
```

That will give you some output that might look something like this:

```
* eba40bf (delete-person) Improve error checking
* 18d630d Implement main delete person functionality
*   ffdf79f (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'insert-person'
|\  
| * d0b6dbb Add more features for person inserting
| * 95312ee Implement main insert person functionality
|/  
* a65c0f4 ...
```

If you have already deleted your insert branch, you need to undo that. To do so, find the last commit of your insert branch, in this case `d0b6dbb`. Then do:

```
git branch insert-person d0b6dbb
```

Next, reset `master`, and start an interactive rebase for `insert-person`:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD^
git checkout insert-person
git rebase -i master
```

Change the first commit from `pick` to `edit`, so your rebase-todo file looks something like this:

```
edit 95312ee Implement main insert person functionality
pick d0b6dbb Add more features for person inserting
```

Then fix the folder structure and continue the rebase:

```
mkdir PERSON
git mv INSERT_PERSON PERSON/
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

At this point, Git is smart enough that it should apply all your other commits without issues, and any other changes should be applied to the new location in the proper folder.

Then you can merge:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff insert-person
```

If the `delete-person` branch hadn't been rebased yet, then you could have done the same for it. However, since it has been rebased, then you'll have to do this:

```
git rebase -i --onto master ffdf79f delete-person
```

And then continue as with the previous rebase.

This will give you a nice clean history, and it will appear as though the folder structure was correct from the beginning.

```
*   0aa9452 (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'delete-person'
|\  
| * ebcbf01 (delete-person) Improve error checking
| * 1a6ae32 Implement main delete person functionality
|/  
*   8591d39 Merge branch 'insert-person'
|\  
| * ca85ff3 (insert-person) Add more features for person inserting
| * 790f60f Implement main insert person functionality
|/  
* a65c0f4 ...
```

---

With Git, it is **very** hard to mess things up so bad that you lose data, especially in cases such as your own where you have several copies of the repo. So as long as you stay away from arguments like `--force`/`-f`, etc., then it's okay to experiment with different solutions to see which you like better.